# Ошибка Serverless Error: Serverless plugin "serverless-offline" not found

Tags: node.js, mongodb, lambda

Скачал с гитхаба: `https://github.com/adnanrahic/building-a-serverless-rest-api-with-nodejs`

Выполняю:

```
npm install
sls deploy
```

и выскакивает ошибка:

`Serverless plugin "serverless-offline" not found. Make sure it's installed and listed in the "plugins"`.

В package.json `serverless-offline` прописан, а вот в папке `node_modules` я его не обнаружил.

Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй:

```
npm install serverless -g
npm install --save-dev
```

Comment: ошибка осталась, в node_modules никакого упоминания 
serverless-offline так и нет.

Comment: Вот статья, пот которой я собственно и пробую запустить проект: https://hackernoon.com/building-a-serverless-rest-api-with-node-js-and-mongodb-2e0ed0638f47

Comment: ```/var/www/rest-api$ git clone https://github.com/adnanrahic/building-a-serverless-rest-api- 
    with-nodejs.git .```
    /var/www/rest-api$ npm i
    /var/www/rest-api$ sls deploy
    Serverless: Packaging service...
    Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
    ServerlessError: AWS provider credentials not found. Learn how to set up AWS provider 
   credentials in our docs here: <http://bit.ly/aws-creds-setup>.

   node -v v8.11.1
   npm -v 4.6.1

Comment: В общем попробовал у меня кидает ошибку на креды, но я их и не заполнял
```sls deploy
Serverless: Packaging service...
Serverless: Excluding development dependencies...
  ServerlessError: AWS provider credentials not found. Learn how to set up AWS provider credentials in our docs here: <http://bit.ly/aws-creds-setup>.
  Your Environment Information -----------------------------
     OS:                     linux
     Node Version:           8.11.1
     Serverless Version:     1.38.0
```
node 8.11.1
npm 4.6.1
просто сделал `npm i` в папке с репозиторием
что то не умею я в стили

Comment: возможно стоит попробовать сделать npm i serverless-offline --save
просто посмотреть запустится или нет после этого